# Could not find rake-13.0.1 in any of the sources while Rails Capistrano deploy

Tags: ruby-on-rails, deployment, capistrano, bundler, vps

Im trying to solve it whole day. I have Ruby on Rails project and trying to deploy it on VPS server. But got same error every time (sometimes with different gems names):

```
Run `bundle install` to install missing gems.
#<Thread:0x00007f81e3b6ed80@/Users/ruslan/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/sshkit-1.21.0/lib/sshkit/runners/parallel.rb:10 run> terminated with exception (report_on_exception is true):
Traceback (most recent call last):
    13: from /Users/ruslan/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/sshkit-1.21.0/lib/sshkit/runners/parallel.rb:12:in `block (2 levels) in execute'
    12: from /Users/ruslan/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/sshkit-1.21.0/lib/sshkit/backends/abstract.rb:31:in `run'
    11: from /Users/ruslan/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/sshkit-1.21.0/lib/sshkit/backends/abstract.rb:31:in `instance_exec'
    10: from /Users/ruslan/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/capistrano-bundler-1.6.0/lib/capistrano/tasks/bundler.cap:26:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
     9: from /Users/ruslan/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/sshkit-1.21.0/lib/sshkit/backends/abstract.rb:92:in `within'
     8: from /Users/ruslan/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/capistrano-bundler-1.6.0/lib/capistrano/tasks/bundler.cap:27:in `block (4 levels) in <top (required)>'
     7: from /Users/ruslan/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/sshkit-1.21.0/lib/sshkit/backends/abstract.rb:100:in `with'
     6: from /Users/ruslan/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/capistrano-bundler-1.6.0/lib/capistrano/tasks/bundler.cap:39:in `block (5 levels) in <top (required)>'
     5: from /Users/ruslan/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/sshkit-1.21.0/lib/sshkit/backends/abstract.rb:80:in `execute'
     4: from /Users/ruslan/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/sshkit-1.21.0/lib/sshkit/backends/abstract.rb:148:in `create_command_and_execute'
     3: from /Users/ruslan/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/sshkit-1.21.0/lib/sshkit/backends/abstract.rb:148:in `tap'
     2: from /Users/ruslan/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/sshkit-1.21.0/lib/sshkit/backends/abstract.rb:148:in `block in create_command_and_execute'
     1: from /Users/ruslan/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/sshkit-1.21.0/lib/sshkit/backends/netssh.rb:170:in `execute_command'
/Users/ruslan/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/sshkit-1.21.0/lib/sshkit/command.rb:97:in `exit_status=': bundle exit status: 7 (SSHKit::Command::Failed)
bundle stdout: Could not find rake-13.0.1 in any of the sources
Run `bundle install` to install missing gems.
bundle stderr: Nothing written
    1: from /Users/ruslan/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/sshkit-1.21.0/lib/sshkit/runners/parallel.rb:11:in `block (2 levels) in execute'
/Users/ruslan/.rbenv/versions/2.6.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/sshkit-1.21.0/lib/sshkit/runners/parallel.rb:15:in `rescue in block (2 levels) in execute': Exception while executing as deploy@199.192.25.241: bundle exit status: 7 (SSHKit::Runner::ExecuteError)
bundle stdout: Could not find rake-13.0.1 in any of the sources
Run `bundle install` to install missing gems.
bundle stderr: Nothing written
(Backtrace restricted to imported tasks)
cap aborted!
SSHKit::Runner::ExecuteError: Exception while executing as deploy@199.192.25.241: bundle exit status: 7
bundle stdout: Could not find rake-13.0.1 in any of the sources
Run `bundle install` to install missing gems.
bundle stderr: Nothing written


Caused by:
SSHKit::Command::Failed: bundle exit status: 7
```

**Gemfile**

```
group :development do
  gem 'capistrano', '~> 3.6'
  gem 'capistrano-bundler', '~> 1.6'
  gem 'capistrano-passenger', '~> 0.2.0'
  gem 'capistrano-rails', '~> 1.4'
  gem 'capistrano-rbenv', '~> 2.1', '>= 2.1.4'
```

**Capfile**

```
# frozen_string_literal: true

# Load DSL and set up stages
require 'capistrano/setup'

# Include default deployment tasks
require 'capistrano/deploy'

# Load the SCM plugin appropriate to your project:
#
# require "capistrano/scm/hg"
# install_plugin Capistrano::SCM::Hg
# or
# require "capistrano/scm/svn"
# install_plugin Capistrano::SCM::Svn
# or
require 'capistrano/scm/git'
install_plugin Capistrano::SCM::Git

# Include tasks from other gems included in your Gemfile
#
# For documentation on these, see for example:
#
#   https://github.com/capistrano/rvm
#   https://github.com/capistrano/rbenv
#   https://github.com/capistrano/chruby
#   https://github.com/capistrano/bundler
#   https://github.com/capistrano/rails
#   https://github.com/capistrano/passenger
#
# require "capistrano/rvm"
require 'capistrano/rbenv'
require 'capistrano/rails'
# require "capistrano/chruby"
require 'capistrano/bundler'
# require 'capistrano/rails/assets'
# require 'capistrano/rails/migrations'
require "capistrano/passenger"

# Load custom tasks from `lib/capistrano/tasks` if you have any defined
Dir.glob('lib/capistrano/tasks/*.rake').each { |r| import r }

set :rbenv_type, :user
set :rbenv_ruby, '2.6.5'
```

**deploy.rb**

```
# frozen_string_literal: true

# config valid for current version and patch releases of Capistrano
lock '~> 3.14.1'

set :application, 'project'
set :repo_url, 'git@github.com:ruvaleev/project_x.git'

# server 'boomboom.best', roles: %i[app]
# set :ssh_options, user: 'root'

# Default branch is :master
# set(:branch, proc { `git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD`.chomp }.call)
# set(:branch, ENV['BRANCH']) if ENV['BRANCH']

# Default deploy_to directory is /var/www/my_app_name
set :deploy_to, "/home/deploy/#{fetch :application}"

set :bundle_jobs, 1

# Default value for :format is :airbrussh.
set :format, :pretty
set :log_level, :debug

# You can configure the Airbrussh format using :format_options.
# These are the defaults.
# set :format_options, command_output: true, log_file: "log/capistrano.log", color: :auto, truncate: :auto

# Default value for :pty is false
set :pty, true

# Default value for :linked_files is []
# append :linked_files, 'config/database.yml'
# set :linked_dirs, fetch(:linked_dirs, []) << '.bundle'
append :linked_dirs, '.bundle', 'vendor/bundle', 'log', 'tmp/pids', 'tmp/cache', 'tmp/sockets', 'public/system', 'public/uploads'

set :rbenv_type, :user
set :rbenv_ruby, '2.6.5'
set :rbenv_prefix, "RBENV_ROOT=#{fetch(:rbenv_path)} RBENV_VERSION=#{fetch(:rbenv_ruby)} #{fetch(:rbenv_path)}/shims/bundle exec" # rubocop:disable Layout/LineLength
# set :rbenv_map_bins, %w[rake gem bundle ruby rails]
set :rbenv_roles, :all # default value

# Default value for linked_dirs is []
# append :linked_dirs, "log", "tmp/pids", "tmp/cache", "tmp/sockets", "public/system"

# Default value for default_env is {}
set :default_env, rails_env: fetch(:stage, '$HOME/.rbenv')
# set :default_env, { path: "~/.rbenv/shims:~/.rbenv/bin:$PATH" }

# Default value for local_user is ENV['USER']
# set :local_user, -> { `git config user.name`.chomp }

# Default value for keep_releases is 5
set :keep_releases, 5

# Uncomment the following to require manually verifying the host key before first deploy.
# set :ssh_options, verify_host_key: :secure
```

when Im coming to server as 'deploy' user (same as in deploy.rb file), I can run `rake --version`
and got

```
rake, version 13.0.1
```

I've trying to set Gemfile and Gemfile.lock on server and every time `bundle` runs without any errors. But when I run `cap production deploy`, I got same error. What am i doing wrong and how to fix it? I've try every advise I found on stackoverflow and web, but nothing works for me, I have no idea why.

1. I've changed bundler version from 2.1.4 to 1.17.3
2. I've removed all rake versions and reinstall them again
3. I've wrote paths to ruby version to nginx config and have reload it after that
4. I've trying to install gems with --path vendor/cache both locally and on server manually
5. I've remover BUNDLE_PATH constant from **.bundle/config** file

But I still got same error. Hope I will find some help here, thank you in advance very very much!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the error was in path rbenv choose for gemset. It stores the path in **$BUNDlE_PATH** variable and after this variable was declared first time, it is storing in some undercover configs. I've deleted project's folder on server and run `cap production deploy` again, and it works fine now. Maybe it will be usefull for somebody

Answer (score -1):

Looks like you not specified `deploy_user` parameter in the `deploy.rb` file. It may cause nasty problems with your Ruby environment. For instance, here my `deploy.rb` config.

```
set :application, 'backend'
set :repo_url, 'git@github.com:some/backend.git'
set :deploy_to, '/home/deploy/backend'
set :deploy_user, 'deploy'
# set :chruby_ruby, 'ruby-2.6.3'
set :nginx_use_ssl, true
set :puma_init_active_record, true
set :linked_files, fetch(:linked_files, []).push('config/database.yml')
set :linked_dirs, fetch(:linked_dirs, []).push('log', 'tmp/pids', 'tmp/cache', 'tmp/sockets', 'public/system')
set :keep_releases, 2
```

Comment: Btw, I have various working capistrano configs, feel free to ask me more.

Comment: I have `server '<server_adress>', user: 'deploy', roles: %w[app db web]` in my **deploy/production.rb** file. But now I've tried to add your variant to **deploy.rb** file and nothing changed